# Ошибка 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Получаю `id` всех в конференции, далее создаю или получаю игрока по его `id`, но выдает эту ошибку:  Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable в коде ниже

> p, _ = await self.pwmanager.get_or_create(self.player, user_id=user['id'])

Мой код:

```
   if admin and (cmd.lower().startswith("раздать")):
            try:
                c, a = cmd.lower().split()
                a = int(a)  
            except ValueError:
                self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

                return await msg.answer(".азино раздать [сумма] - раздать всем участникам конфы указанную сумму")

            except Exception:
                import traceback
                traceback.print_exc()

                self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
                return await msg.answer("Произошла ошибка.") 

            bett = a

            all_users = await msg.api.messages.getChatUsers(chat_id=msg.chat_id)

            for user in all_users:
                p, _ = await self.pwmanager.get_or_create(self.player, user_id=user['id'])
                p.balance += bett

            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
            return await msg.answer(f"Я выдала всем в этой конфе {str(bett)}$")
```

Comment: Это не ошибка, это строка кода.

Comment: отредактировал сообщение

Comment: В ошибке написано, что переменная `user` содержит число, а запись вида `1['id']` бессмысленна.

Comment: чтобы не путаться можно написать: `for user_id in all_user_ids: ... get_or_create(..., user_id=user_id)`

Comment: Спасибо большое